# Powershell and csv file: How do I tell powershell to skip/ignore a data in a cell if it doesn't exist and move on to the next

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

Newbie here..
Working with powershell and csv. How do I tell powershell to ignore whatever it can't find and do the rest?
My current scripts is this..

```
 $Snumber=Import-csv c:\temp\Snumber.csv
 Foreach($EmployeeID in $Snumber)
{
 Add-ADGroupMember -Identity “Group” -Members $Snumber.EmployeeID 
}
```

It works only if there is an existing data, but it errors if the data doesn't exist and doesn't complete or do the rest to insert into AD for me.  I don't mind the error, but as long as it keeps on moving and doing the rest, I be fine with it.

I've try Adding things like using $ErrorAction = ‘continue’. But won't work.

Comment: Change from : $Snumber.EmployeeID  To : $EmployeeID.EmployeeID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you're referencing `$Snumber.EmployeeID`, when `$Snumber` is the collection being enumerated and what you actually wanted to reference was `$EmployeeID.EmployeeId`. So changing only this should fix the problem, users that could be added will be added but still you would see errors in the console.

You can however implement some error handling in case you wanted, first you can query all users in your CSV and gather all that could be found in one array `$usersFound`, then you can feed that array to `Add-ADGroupMember` since `-Members` takes `ADPrincipal[]` as input.

```bash
$usersFound = foreach($user in Import-csv c:\temp\Snumber.csv) {
    try {
        Get-ADUser $user.EmployeeId
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning $_
    }
}

try {
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity theGroup -Members $usersFound
}
catch {
    Write-Warning $_
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
Foreach($EmployeeID in $Snumber)
{
    # check if user exists in AD
    $User = Get-ADUser -Identity $Snumber.EmployeeID -Properties * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($null -eq $User) 
        {Write-Host "User does not exist"}
    else { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity “Group” -Members $User }

}
```

more cleanly:

```
Try
{
  $User = Get-ADUser -Identity $Snumber.EmployeeID -Properties *  -ErrorAction Stop
  Add-ADGroupMember -Identity “Group” -Members $User
}
Catch 
{ 
  {Write-Host "User does not exist"}
}
```

Comment: AD Cmdlets produce terminating errors no matter the error action preference.